# JDBC JAVA SE application cannot read all tables in ORACLE R12

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc

I made a SQL query in SQL developer for Oracle R12 Database which works fine. There are several tables/views. All these object are accessible under LOGIN and PASSWORD which I use.

I created an old JAVA SE application using JDBC driver and trying to select data from same source (database). It works just for some objects (tables, views). In mention SQL query I use 8 tables, 4 are not working (not error, just blank data).

> NO DATA FOUND (no error, seems like he cannot read any rows from that tables/views)

I have following code

```
    try {
        String query = "SELECT status_name FROM APPS.WSH_DELIVERABLE_TRIPS_V WHERE TRUNC(CREATION_DATE) = TRUNC(SYSDATE)";

        //Database.getConnection().setTransactionIsolation(Connection.TRANSACTION_READ_COMMITTED);

        PreparedStatement prep = Database.getConnection().prepareStatement(query, Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);
        // prep.setInt(1, delivery);
        ResultSet rs = prep.executeQuery();

        ResultSetMetaData c = rs.getMetaData(); 

        System.out.println("COLUMNS: " + c.getColumnCount());

        System.out.println("RS " + rs.next());

        //System.out.println("FIRST: " + String.valueOf(rs.first()));
        //createStatement(java.sql.ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE,java.sql.ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY);

        while (rs.next()) {
            dataFound = true;
            // textInfo.setText("Data was found!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!");
            //textInfo.setText(rs.getString(1) + " - " + rs.getString(2) + " - " + rs.getString(3));
            //String test = String.valueOf(rs.getString("status_name")) + textInfo.getText();
            textInfo.setText(String.valueOf(rs.getString(1)));
        }

        if (dataFound) {
            loadingImg.setVisible(false);
        } else {
            loadingImg.setVisible(false);
            textInfo.setText("No data found.");
        }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        ExceptionWindow excep = new ExceptionWindow(e); //Show error Window
    }
```

Comment: **NO DATA FOUND** means that you tried to select data from a table with some conditions and there was no matching records found. This, of course, does not mean that you cannot retrieve data. It only means that there is no data matching your criteria.

Comment: What do you get running your query directly in your SQL Developer? Same result I guess!

Comment: No, even I run sql query for example: "SELECT * FROM APPS.WSH_DELIVERABLE_TRIPS_V" it seems there is not row. In SQL developer it works fine, milion lines are retrieved. It does not work for 50% tables. I have no idea why.

Comment: I found root cause, views does not work because of this line and command WHERE LANGUAGE = userenv('LANG') -> userenv

Answer (score 0):

I think you have problem in this line

```
PreparedStatement prep = Database.getConnection().prepareStatement(query, Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);
```

Connection contains different overloaded method of prepareStatement(). You have used below method.

> **prepareStatement(String sql, int autoGeneratedKeys)**
>
> Creates a default PreparedStatement object that has the capability to retrieve auto-generated keys.

This method should used for **insert purpose not for the select**. I believe if you use below method, then you will get the expected results.

> **prepareStatement(String sql)**
>
> Creates a PreparedStatement object for sending parameterized SQL statements to the database.

Comment: Bikku,
I tried to changed line to following and still issue:

            PreparedStatement prep = Database.getConnection().prepareStatement(query);

also I got from sout following:
COLUMNS: 1
RS false

Comment: Please remove the where caluse from query and also remove the System.out.println("RS " + rs.next()); and then run it and share the output

Comment: Bikku, issue was function in view called

Comment: Bikku, issue was function in view called 'userenv' -> session property for lang ('LANG'), When I change this SQL query without this function 'userenv' it works fine! Can I set session variable in JDBC?

Comment: Yes, you can set session variable in JDBC DB url.

Comment: Can you give me example please? Thanks